# Turn off encryption on filevault2 second HDD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, filevault

I have an Early 2011 MBP on which I installed an SSD (in the SuperDrive's bay).
After that I enabled FileVault2 encryption on both the SSD (which has the ML 1.8.2 install) and on the original HDD that's currently mounted at boot-time on /Users (so all the storage for the users go on it and it's still encrypted no matter what).

I would like to add a second (and maybe a third?) partition to the HDD so that I can experiment with Windows 8 (and maybe the latest Ubuntu?) but the error I receive is

**Error: -69741: The target disk isn't eligible for reversion because it wasn't created by conversion or it is not part of a simple setup of exactly one logical and one physical volume**

Is there anything to do ?

Answer (score 6):

What methods have you used when trying to disabling the encryption on your encrypted non-boot drive? Here's some ways I know about:

**Using Disk Utility**

1. Boot your Mac and hold down ⌘-R (Command –R) to boot from the Mac’s Recovery HD partition.
2. Open Disk Utility.
3. Select your locked hard drive.
4. Under the **File** menu, select **Turn Off Encryption…**
5. When prompted for a password, you can enter your password for the drive. Once provided, decryption of the encrypted volume should begin.

The drive should begin decrypting.

**From the command line**

1. Boot your Mac and hold down ⌘-R (Command –R) to boot from the Mac’s Recovery HD partition.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Run the following command to get the UUID of the encrypted drive: `diskutil corestorage list`
4. Once you have the UUID, you can unlock the drive using the following command: `diskutil corestorage revert UUID -stdinpassphrase`
5. You’ll be prompted for the password/passphrase of an account that’s authorized to unlock the encryption. Once provided, decryption of the encrypted volume should begin.

The drive should begin decrypting.

For more information, see here:

[Unlock or decrypt your FileVault 2-encrypted boot drive from the command line](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/using-the-command-line-to-unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-2-encrypted-boot-drive/)

[Using Disk Utility to unlock or decrypt your FileVault 2-encrypted boot drive](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/using-disk-utility-to-unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-2-encrypted-boot-drive/)

Comment: You are describing how to unlock the boot drive, not the second drive. I ended up making a TimeMachine backup and just wiping the drive... :(

Comment: This works exactly the same way.

Comment: I don't see `Turn Off Encryption` in Mojave's disk utility when in recovery mode. `diskutil corestorage list` returns empty

Answer (score 1):

Just enable root user via the control panel.
Then login via root and you will have access to the files on the file vault partition.